# Understandable error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo & Didn't find class

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

To fix the errors mentioned:
    - Import the app support libraries as projects from sdk/extras/android/support/v7

Now I have this error:

```
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): Process: com.tfg.webquest, PID: 1749
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.tfg.webquest/com.tfg.webquest.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tfg.webquest.SplashScreenActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tfg.webquest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.tfg.webquest-1, /system/lib]]
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tfg.webquest.SplashScreenActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tfg.webquest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.tfg.webquest-1, /system/lib]]
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
12-04 05:54:16.067: E/AndroidRuntime(1749):     ... 11 more
```

I have solve the java.lang.NoSuchFieldError that I had at the beginning.

Can be useful this information to solve the error:(thank you)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tfg.webquest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.tfg.webquest.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterCourseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_course" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterSubjectActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_subject" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterSubjectsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list_view_checkboxes" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuestIntroActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_quest_intro_activity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".QuestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_quest_activity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StatisticActivity"
        android:label="@string/StatisticActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameFinishedActivity"
        android:label="@string/GameFinishedActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you add android support library v7 properly to your project? It appears you didn't, because compiler cannot find a valid resource from it.

Comment: Yes. In this link you can see what it is added to my project. Thank you. http://i58.tinypic.com/2r5c4sk.png

Comment: have you missing super.onCreate() first line in onCreate() ?

Comment: You have three different dependencies connected with android support library v7. You should have only one and it should be under Android Private Libraries. Follow this to configure your poject correctly [support v7](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). Especially 'Adding libraries with resources' section.

Comment: Yes thank you. I forgot to include it in the code. But I get the same error that before.

Comment: The most common Eclipse solution: did you try Project > Clean? 

Comment: @michal.z I have copied the support libraries v4 and v7 to the libs folder of my project. And I have added to my project: http://i58.tinypic.com/szzgqa.png is this correct? My error persists

Comment: @JaredRummler I have done it lot of times haha thank you

Comment: AppCompat isn't just a jar, it has resources. You need to import the project and add it to your main project as a library. See the link michal.z posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can sum up comments discussion in an answer as it's obvious now. You're not adding android support library v7 correctly to your project. You have to add it as an Android library (with resources) not only the jar to libs folder. Follow [support v7](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

Comment: thank you so much, it has solve one of my errors. No I have a new one